# Rewriting search term in URL using htaccess and mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Currently I have this rewrite rule in place and it works great:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/? search.php?term=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

When I go to `mysite.com/search/foo` it takes me to the proper search page for `foo`. what I am looking to do is make the opposite work as well so that if I visit `mysite.com/search.php?term=foo` I will be taken to `mysite.com/search/foo`. I think I need a 301 redirect somewhere but I'm not sure how to do it without creating an infinite loop and the other posts I've read so far haven't been much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /search\.php\?term=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^search\.php$ /search/%1/? [L,R=301]
```

or (if you place these *after* the rule that you already have

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^term=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^search\.php$ /search/%1/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: The first one didn't seem to do anything, the second one forwards me to the correct page /search/foo but gives a 404.

Comment: @Riboflavin sorry, forgot to escape the \? from the first set of rules

Comment: @Riboflavin If `/search/foo/` gives you a 404, does going directly to `http://mysite.com/search/foo/` also give you a 404?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+mysite.com/search.php?term=foo [NC]
RewriteRule ^ mysite.com/search/foo [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `R` flag to your `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/? search.php?term=$1 [NC,QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: But that is for redirect 301, he wants the other way around